# One North African Civilization Or More?

Tags: culture, alternate-history, geography, civilization

[image]

Throughout pre-Roman history, North Africa and the Middle East had its fair share of civilizations--not just the popular Egyptians, but also the Carthaginians, the Sumerians, the Assyrians, the Babylonians and the Hittites.  The reason that there were so many civilizations in so small area sizes is simple--**they built their cities in deserts!**  Even on the Mediterranean coast, the environments in Israel, Syria, Lebanon, Jordan and Iraq are so extreme that farming and irrigation would require an extra degree of ingenuity.

Things are no better off in the Sahara, either.  Highs average around 104 degrees Fahrenheit, it is sandy mixed with rocky and the Nile, as far as I know, is the only river that can cut through the desert rock and sand and to the Mediterranean.

In this alternate Africa, things are a little different.  For starters, North Africa is 100% rock, which means none of the sand dunes that made Arabia or the Sahara so notorious.

[image]

North Africa has its own series of Great Lakes.  (Though this map does not take rivers into account, and Lake Chad, in this scenario, is not of an accurate shape or area size.)

[image]

A more accurate Lake Chad.  (Again, the map does not take rivers into account.)

[image]

In this alternate Earth, Arabia is a mere extension of northeastern Africa, erasing both the Red Sea and the Gulf of Aden off the map.  Also, the mountains are arranged differently.  The Atlas Mountains still stand by the Sahara’s northwestern coast, but they are taller — the tallest peak being 21,810 feet above the level of the sea, 1500 feet taller than Denali.  Outlining the coasts of Angola, Namibia, South Africa, Mozambique, Tanzania, Kenya, Somalia, Yemen and Oman is a range of volcanic mountains called the Aden Bahçesi. Its highest peak stands 24,341 feet above sea level, 1500 feet higher than Aconcagua back home. All of Africa’s rivers originate from those two mountain ranges.

Now let's take the possible effects of civilization into account.  Would these changes create larger civilizations, perhaps even full-blown empires (at least before the Macedonians and Romans marched along)?

Comment: There's no telling, this is too broad, again...

Comment: Can't you at least TRY?

Comment: All I can suggest is to look at what culture existed in the area throughout history and go from there.

Comment: Evaporation happens, that's a starter. Then Persia manage to subjugate the whole continent. Make sense since it's the great power of the time.

Comment: @Vincent  "Evaporation"?

Comment: Your version of history is confused. The Assyrians and Sumerians lived in the Middle East, not North Africa. As well, the climate was much different even into Roman times (North Africa was forested, for example), as well as the infrastructure (the ancient Middle East was criss crossed with irrigation systems, many which were destroyed by the Muslim conquest in the first millennium AD). And outside of that, the question is too broad. try researching the real history of a small sub region and then ask or speculate what the changes would do there to start...

Comment: @Thucydides In this alternate scenario, the MidEast IS a part of Africa.

Comment: Sorry, but no. Africa is an entirely separate continent from Eurasia.

Comment: @Thucydides: I'd note that not only was the climate of North Africa & the Middle East different in the past, it was largely human activity that was (and still is) responsible for the changes.  Also, many of the civilizations mentioned were separated not just by geography, but by time.

Comment: A question you need to answer is what caused your African Great Lakes.  They don't just appear by magic, and generally don't last long, in geologic time.  The North American Great Lakes are the result of glaciation during the last Ice Ages, something that's not likely to have happened in Africa.  Other large lakes - Victoria, Tanganyika &c in Africa, Baikal in Asia - are located in rift valleys.  Other than those, there really aren't any large lakes that I can think of.

Comment: Of course there are the former endorheic lakes of the US Great Basin (Lahontan, Bonneville, &c), but those either dried up or drained through erosion (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonneville_flood ), and again, have geological causes.

Comment: @Thucydides  The MidEast is an extension of northeastern Africa in this alternate Earth.

Comment: @jamesqf  Enormous depressions, tectonic rifts or volcanic calderas reshaped and filled in by ice, rain and river.

Comment: The lakes are located in a desert. The water will evaporate.

Comment: @Vincent  With so many lakes and rivers, how can we be sure it will still be a desert?

Comment: Because, like said many times already, the climates generates the rivers/lakes, not the opposite.

Comment: @Vincent  Mountains generate the rivers.  It's common knowledge.

Comment: Your simplifying things a bit and that's assuming there is enough water to sustain this environment. The main issue is that your blocking a large source of precipitations, the Indian ocean. Thus making Africa interior a lot drier.

Comment: @Vincent  The equator is where moisture rises up to the atmosphere, condensing into rain.  https://andrealiang.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/heatenergytransfer2-e1397323937582.jpg

Comment: @JohnWDailey: To get "enormous depressions" or more rift valleys, you really have to change the geologic history, which means going back to plate tectonics, which means everything else changes, too.  Volcanic craters just aren't big enough.  Though in fact there is a good-sized endorheic basin in northern Africa, so you just have to work on getting enough precipitation to fill it: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Ocean_drainage.png

Comment: @jamesqf  Why do you tempt me to spill the whole thing at once at you?